# How do you view enemy unit attack ranges?

Tags: tactics-ogre-psp

In most, if not all, SRPG or turn-based strategy games you can put your cursor over an enemy unit, and press a button to view their attack range.  I know you can view their movement range, which helps for direct attack units, but I have to manually calculate ranged units.

So, how do you view an enemy unit's attack range?  Assuming it's possible, but I can't imagine that probably the most comprehensive SRPG of all time doesn't have that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Because here's a fun fact: Ranged attacks can hit WELL beyond their listed ranges.  It's based on the relative height differences between the unit and their target.  The higher the unit is, the farther they can reach.  Archers on walls (because they have Warp Rings or Winged Boots), can sometimes target the entire map.  Obstacles will also play a part for Gunners; they need a direct line to their target, whereas Archers will just shoot over them.

The only limitation for ranged attacks are spells; those, the range isn't extendable, but is still subject to obstacles.

Melee is the only one you can figure out; it's the unit's movement range, and then add one for all melee weapons, and add an extra one for whips and spears.